# Undefined Variable for sum(value) AS "Variable" SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm currently struggling to get one of my variable defined. I have this query:

```
 $query = 'SELECT e.Emp_ID, e.Name, sum(c.Price) AS "Sales"
        FROM Employees e 
        JOIN Sales s 
        on e.Emp_ID = s.Emp_ID 
        JOIN Carmodels c 
        ON c.Car_ID = s.Car_ID
        GROUP BY e.name
        ORDER BY e.Emp_ID';
```

witch gets the data from my db to my php project. In the PHP project I'm trying to create an array like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row); 

        $emp_item = array(
            'Emp_ID' => $Emp_ID, 
            'Name' => $Name, 
            'Sales' => $Sales
        );

        array_push($emp_array['data'], $emp_item); 
    }

    echo json_encode($emp_array);
```

But I get "Undefined variable: Sales" which makes the variable unable to use. Do you know what might cause this and how to solve it?

Comment: This whole shebang is completely unnecessary. `array_push($emp_array['data'], $row);` would yield the same exact result. You extract values from an associative array into variables and then assign those variable values to an associative array with the same keys. You got back to where you started.

Comment: Well to be honest, i thought this is where they gets defined since that's how it works for the other ones $Emp_ID and $Name...

Comment: @El_Vanja someway true, but then it only show the other two colums...

Comment: That's a symptom of the same problem you have now. For some reason, your sum isn't fetched alongside the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the section of code that actually executes the SQL query.  Something like...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result = $mysqli->query($query)

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $emp_item = array(
        'Emp_ID' => $row['Emp_ID'], 
        'Name' => $row['Name'], 
        'Sales' => $row['Sales']
    );
    // do more with $emp_item here

  }
```

Comment: For the next time: this should be a comment, not an answer :)